# How to create two pair of page header and details in crystal report

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm new beginner in crystal reports and I know the basics of it.
I just create a report with one page header section and one detail section.
My concern now is how to create a pair of page header and detail.
When I adding a new detail section it just going to be a nested details section. 
I want a output just like this:

```
-Page Header 1
--Detail 1

-Page Header 2
--Detail 2
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use sub reports.

In one main report take 2 sub reports... one pair in one sub report and second pair in 2nd sub report